# Does Take() force LINQ to enumerate the result IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following two queries

```
List<User> allUsers= dbContext.Users.ToList();
List<User> topTenUsers = dbContext.Users.Take(10).ToList();
```

They are properties of an instance class and they both load data like the code below:

```
using (var dbContext = new fooDataObjects.DataContext()) { 
    //...they are loaded here
}
```

The question is, when i try to access the result collection from `allUsers` i get an exception which says "Cannot access a disposed object."  But the same way i can access the result collection from `topTenUsers`.

Does Take() force LINQ to enumerate the result elements that i can get the result from the second collection?

Comment: Do `User` objects have dependent objects? Does the error happen only when you try accessing these dependents, but accessing attributes of `User` itself is OK?

Comment: are you sure you copied your code correctly? And no - Take does not enforce enumeration of `IQueryable`

Comment: In your code what enforces enumeration are the **ToList** calls.

Comment: When accessing `allUsers` you will not get that problem, since a `List<T>` does in no way create a dependency on the original source of its elements. *However*, the **elements** themselves might be disposed. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "access the result collection ..."?

Comment: Just before the error shows up, try to call .Count() on allUsers to see if it passes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Take()` on its own doesn't cause an enumeration of the underlying sequence.

However, the `.ToList()` you have there *will* cause it to be enumerated (although only the first 10 elements, in your sample case).

I think the reason you're getting an exception in the case where you don't use `Take(10)` is because one of the objects after the first 10 has been disposed, but none of the first 10 have been disposed.

Thus only the complete list contains a disposed object; the partial list is fine.